# Animation resets states of child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a framer motion component (I've tried with [Stitches components](https://stitches.dev/docs/composing-components) too) that animates to and from view based on a useState variable:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

<motion.div
    animate={visible ? "one" : "two"}
    variants={{
      one: {
        transform: "translateX(0%)",
        opacity: 1
      },
      two: {
        transform: "translateX(100%)",
        opacity: 0
      }
    }}
  >
  // children
</motion.div>
```

The children components are wrapped in contexts, and the problem is that their states reset every time the animation is triggered.

I've tried declaring the animation component outside of its current scope. In its current scope it resets the states of everything except the "currentUser" state in my AuthProvider context. Outside the scope it resets "currentUser" too. I've decided not to include the original code for brevity.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-water-6n8h5?file=/src/AuthContext.jsx) is a minimum reproducible. If you type something in the input, and then click the toggle button, the input is lost.

Answer (score 1):

`DummyInputComponent` should be stateless, use the value provided by the context and also have a onChange handler function passed on from the context

Something like this:

```js
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [dummyValue, setDummyValue] = useState(null);

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    setDummyValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const value = {
    dummyValue,
    onChange: handlechange
  };

  const DummyInputComponent = () => {
    return <input value={value.dummyValue || ""} onChange={value.onChange} />;
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      <DummyInputComponent />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-surf-gljof?file=/src/AuthContext.jsx:172-651)

Comment: I see... Well this works for my provided example, but in my real app I'm dealing with multiple nested components and contexts, and it feels like this would make it extremely messy. Would you recommend the same in that situation?

Comment: Hard to judge. If you really want to keep state handling inside the components that have inputs, another work around would be using sessionstorage or localstorage to preserve input values across re-renders caused by frame motion. It's not optimal but it works. I'm still investigating why framer motion cause this hoping to find a better solution, but no luck so far.

Comment: I guess that could work yeah. And yeah I was struggling to find anyone experiencing the same issue, kind of lost on what to google. But thanks for trying, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the common use case for this is for performance tweaking, but I ended up avoiding the rerenders caused by framer motion (supposedly) by using memoization:

```
const Memoized = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

 return (
  <motion.div
    animate={visible ? "one" : "two"}
    variants={{
      one: {
        transform: "translateX(0%)",
        opacity: 1
      },
      two: {
        transform: "translateX(100%)",
        opacity: 0
      }
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </motion.div>
 );
});
```

I don't know if this is a good way to do it, so I'll leave this open.